# AFNetworking 2.0 Amazon PUT request boundary issues

Tags: cocoa, amazon-s3, afnetworking-2

Since ASIHTTPRequest has been abandoned I an moving a ios/osx project over to using AFNetworking 2.0. I have written a category for AFHTTPRequestOperationManager that adds a method to create an Amazon S3 PUT request. It handles all of the signing etc.. which is working great. However, I am running into issues with the images I am uploading. The files are successfully uploaded to S3 but are NOT recognized as valid image (jpg) files. They open in photoshop fine (it must be forgiving) but nothing else. Some digging into the file (running cat ) shows that the end boundary is being encoded into the file

`--Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY--`

I have double checked the HTTP header files and they look correct:

```
"Accept-Language" = "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, zh-Hans;q=0.7, zh-Hant;q=0.6, ja;q=0.5";
Authorization = "AWS REDACTED";
"Content-Length" = 228941;
"Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+0xAbCdEfGbOuNdArY";
Date = "Wed, 30 Oct 2013 18:57:39 +0000";
```

I am building the request using:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"PUT" URLString:url.absoluteString parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:block];
```

The construction block looks like:

```
__weak UploadPhotoAFS3Op *weakSelf = self;
self.constructingBodyBlock = ^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    UploadPhotoAFS3Op *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:resizedPhotoData name:@"image" fileName:strongSelf->_photoToUpload.uuidFileName mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }
};
```

I am sure the resizedPhotoData is valid - this is generated the same way as the currently working ASIHTTPRequest based operation. The issue has something to do with the headers (the boundary specifically) - I am at a loss.